# lua large spaces between print() arguments

Tags: lua

I am trying to display the values of my eight sensors like this:

```
print(sensors[1], sensors[2], sensors[3])
print(sensors[4], "P", sensors[5])
print(sensors[6], sensors[7], sensors[8])
```

(the P stands for Player)

I thought the console would show this:

```
1 0 0
1 P 0
1 0 0
```

But instead it gave me this:

```
1       0       0
1       P       0
1       0       0
```

Why are there large spaces between the different arguments?

Comment: Try `print(sensors[1].." "..sensors[2].." "..sensors[3])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [specified in the documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-print), `print` inserts tabs between each argument, and inserts a newline at the end of what it prints. It is primarily for debugging, and it is a simple tool. If you want more rigid control of what gets printed, use `io.stdout:write`.